# Handling a second UI thread in WPF

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I have a long running process that runs on my UI thread that I cannot move off of the UI thread. Instead I am trying to create a second UI thread that has a waiting animation. Here's the code I'm using to create the second UI thread:

```
Private _busyThread As Thread
Private _waitWindow As WaitWindow 'This is the window with the animation

Private Sub StartBusyIndicator(ByVal busyInfo As BusyInfo)
    _busyThread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf ThreadStartingPoint))
    _busyThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    _busyThread.IsBackground = True
    _busyThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Function ThreadStartingPoint() As ThreadStart
    _waitWindow = New WaitWindow
    _waitWindow.Show()
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
End Function
```

How can I close this gracefully when needed? I can't access `_waitWindow` from the main UI thread to close it. If I issue `_busyThread.Abort()` it doesn't actually close the window.

Comment: If your design insists on running on the UI thread something is probably wrong with it and it's most likely possible to refactor it such that you still have just one UI thread. In the extremely improbable case you *really* need a second UI thread  you can always run a separate process and use named pipes to communicate between the two

Comment: What is the long running process doing on the UI thread? Reed is correct that the process should be moved off the UI.

Comment: Yes, it does need refactoring. I was looking for a quick fix until that time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to close the window:

This marshals the call to close the window into the new window's thread.

This will not shut down that thread, though.  To do that, try:

```
_waitWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
         _waitWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background)
         _waitWindow.Close()
    End Sub)
```

I have an [article on my blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20111225112404/http://reedcopsey.com/2011/11/28/launching-a-wpf-window-in-a-separate-thread-part-1/) which discusses this, as well as other issues, in detail.  It's in C#, but could be converted to VB.Net easily enough.

Note that, in the long run, figuring out how to move the long running process off the main thread will be a better solution, as this will still leave your application as appearing unresponsive to Windows and your end user.

Comment: Should I actually abort the 2nd thread then? Or will it clean itself up?

Comment: @MikeCole Showed how to handle this.

Comment: Great blog post. Was there ever a part 2?