# Skip windows messages when forcing execution of the Dispatcher queue

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher, windows-messages

I am currently forced to update some part of the UI while some lengthy operation is performed on the UI thread. I know this should not be done, but - as I said - I am forced...

I have therefore added the following call to the location where the UI should be updated:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { }, DispatcherPriority.Render);
```

As you may know, this will force the Dispatcher Queue to be processed until all queued delegates up to (and including) priority `Render` have been executed. This way, the UI is updated although the UI thread is currently blocked.

Now, my problem is: When calling the `Invoke` method, the dispatcher queue does not only contain the delegates for re-rendering the UI, but obviously it also contains some custom Windows message. This Windows message is generated by our own application and it will be executed during the `Invoke` call. However, I do not want this because it introduces weird side effects! I only want the UI to be redrawn.

**Is there any way to force UI rendering without processing any other Windows messages?**

I tried to achieve this by calling some Win API functions:

```
private static readonly uint MSG1 = 0xC21E;
private static readonly uint MSG2 = 0xC25D;

// ...

while (PeekMessage(out msg, IntPtr.Zero, MSG1, MSG2, (uint)PeekMessageParams.PM_REMOVE))
{
    TranslateMessage(ref msg);
    DispatchMessage(ref msg);
}
```

`MSG1` and `MSG2` are messages that I found when I inspected the messages in the queue while the UI is blocked and my UI updates are done. I assumed that these messages have something to do with re-rendering the UI, but that assumption is not correct obviously. At least, the UI is not refreshed with the above code.

Any other ideas?

---

**EDIT:**
I just found the [`Dispatcher.Yield()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.yield.aspx) method which was introduced in .NET 4.5. The documentation says:

> Use this method if want to give your app a chance to process events while your app is doing a lot of work on the UI thread. For example, you can use this method in a long-running loop that updates a control.

Does anybody have any experience with this method?

Comment: Can you share the constraint that is forcing the processing to be done in the UI thread? And is there an alternative to Win32 messages you could use to achieve the same functionality? (e.g. using the event aggregator pattern)

Comment: 1) The constraint is that these operations are running on the UI thread and that my boss says it is too complicated and error-prone to move them to a worker thread... (slightly simplified) 2) Unfortunately, there is no alternative to Win32 messages for the same reason as 1). This is a pretty big application and these messages are used all over the place. I hate this task for exactly these reasons, but I have to do it somehow...

Comment: Is it possible to intercept the messages and re-send them?

Comment: @Pete This might be a possible solution, but I do not know how to do this. And I fear that this might also have undesired side effects...

Comment: "it introduces weird side effects" is exactly the reason why you shouldn't do something like `Application.DoEvents()` or alike... Have you tried to set a flag before `Invoke` (+reset it afterwards) and check this flag in WndProc?

Comment: @JeffRSon Thanks for your comment! I know pretty well that `DoEvents` or similar stuff is evil, evil, evil. I would love to get rid of it, but I could not come up with another solution for updating the UI while the UI thread is blocked. Using a flag in the `WndProc` method is not really possible because the message handling happens in a core module which I do not have access to.

Comment: What exactly should be updated in your UI? If it's just for visualizing progress, you may, in such a special case, do this in a second UI thread (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067615/handling-a-second-ui-thread-in-wpf or similar). You can't generally prevent Windows Messages to be processed - that's the whole point of an UI thread...

Comment: @JeffRSon Actually, this looks pretty similar to what I am already doing. I am supposed to display a spinning busy indicator. This busy indicator spins on a different thread, so the animation works properly even though the UI thread is blocked. However, this control needs to be added to the main window somehow. After adding it, the UI thread has to re-render, so that the user can see it spinning. This is where I call the `DoEvents()` equivalent. Unfortunately, it is no solution to open another window for the indicator. It has to be in the main window... :(